# Bare expo app won't compile for Ios: Showing All Messages Build input file cannot be found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, bare

### I created a Bare expo app and tried to run react-native run-ios, I'm getting the following error:

Showing All Messages
*Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testing-fxkbjuawpoifdbcjtioxmqmmeybm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/appname.app/appname'*

I tried making a fresh app but it didn't work.

I also tried to re-build the ios/directory with:
`react-native upgrade --legacy true`

I tried downgrading my react-native version so I could use the above command but I ran into issues.

Edit:
Just for the record, the issue was that my computer's hard drive was almost full, and the app would not be able to compile completely. Yep, software engineering my friends...

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to Xcode 12

Use the non-legacy build system

Comment: Just for the record, the issue was that my computer's hard drive was almost full, and the app would not be able to compile completely. Yep, software engineering my friends...